# whats wrong with my python QT code

Tags: python, qt4, pycharm

This as a downloader code i had written in python QT. And it keeps on showing below error:

```
'C:\Python34\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 3.4.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 52063 --file C:/Users/bablu/PycharmProjects/pydownloader/structure.py
pydev debugger: process 4108 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 135.1057)

Process finished with exit code -1'
```

My code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
import urllib.request

class Downloader(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.url = QLineEdit()
        self.save_location = QLineEdit()
        self.progress = QProgressBar()
        download = QPushButton("Download")


        self.url.setPlaceholderText("URL")
        self.save_location.setPlaceholderText("File Save Location")


        self.progress.setValue(0)
        self.progress.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)


        layout.addWidget(self.url)
        layout.addWidget(self.save_location)
        layout.addWidget(self.progress)
        layout.addWidget(download)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle("python downloader")
        self.setFocus()

        download.clicked.connect(self.download)

    def download(self):
        url = self.url.text()
        save_location = self.save_location.text()
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, save_location, self.report)

        QMessageBox.information(self, "Information", "download complete")

    def report(self, blocknum, blocksize, totalsize):
        readsofar = blocknum * blocksize

        if totalsize > 0:
            percent = readsofar * 100/totalsize
            self.progress.setValue(int(percent))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dl = Downloader()
dl.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

try importing and using `PyQt5` instead. This worked for me.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QProgressBar, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QApplication

import sys
import urllib.request
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a file name instead of folder path
eg "file.ext"